# App store connect App Preview frame rate too low

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm receiving an error message when trying to upload an app preview to the app store connect that says the frame rate of my video is too low. As you can see from the other screenshot below, my frame rate sits at 18 FPS. Apple docs state max FPS allowed is 30, so really unsure what the issue is here? For context i used the IOS simulator screen recorder to get the video

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**FPS = Max Frame Rate.** (in this case)

[Frame Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate)

> Frame rate in electronic camera specifications may refer to the maximal possible rate

That means It **should** be 30 frames per second. believe me from previous experiments, even if it was 29 FPS they will not accept it.